# How to implement user profile in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

How to implement user profile with ASP.NET MVC 3 ?

I need to add additional parameters to default registration and retrieve them back.

Comment: Google is your friend on this one, there are many tutorials and many question on this on SOF.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this helpful article on MSDN: How to secure your ASP.NET MVC 3 Application at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx.

An interesting link for Profile management is the .NET Framework's ProfileBase class, with which you can build custom profiles. You can find its description at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profilebase.aspx.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the link @ https://web.archive.org/web/20211020114106/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/110310-1.aspx

This has good information on asp.net membership and also how to add additional user information.

Answer (score 1):

By default the ASP.NET membership provider system (MSDN reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) uses regular SQL database tables to store its data.

The reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730.aspx describes precisely what you ask.